# Выделяется ли неявно память при вызове функций с локальными переменными?

Tags: память, ассемблер, c++

До этого времени был уверен, что при вызове функции на уровне машинных команд (call) происходит передача регистров/сохранённых значений указателя стека, формирование стекового кадра для вызываемой функции в виде изменения значения указателя стека на объём локальных переменных (а также адреса возврата и ещё чего-то служебного небольшого размера). Коллеги по работе (старшие по возрасту) сказали, что при работе с локальными переменными есть потеря производительности в виде "заказов" и "освобождений" памяти. Насколько я знаю, с помощью c++ такие вещи происходят при `new` `malloc`, `HeapAlloc` (для WinAPI) и т.п. Может быть, действительно, существует некий минимальный стековый кадр, для которого механизм прост (`push ebp \ mov ebp, esp \ sub esp, N \ ... \ mov esp, ebp \ pop ebp \ ret \ ... \ add esp, N`), а при превышении этого размера уже происходит неявное выделение памяти в куче?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Если они говорят с Вами словами *"заказов" памяти*, то либо они малограмотные, либо не уважают Вас. Почему просто не сказать "выделение памяти"?

Но на самом деле тут все интересней, чем они говорят. В некоторых случаях память будет выделятся, в некоторых нет. Все зависит от типа переменой. Например:

- параметр описан как `int x` - скорее всего компилятор просто выделит в стеке/регистре 4/8 байт, а если он жуткооптимизирующий, то потери вообще могут быть нулевые в некоторых случаях.
- вариант два - переменная описана как `MyObject* s` - вот тут будет выделено 4/8 байт в стеке/регистре плюс необходимая память для размещения объекта в памяти (но только когда будет явно вызван конструктор).
- вариант три `MyObject s`  вот тут будет выделенно достаточно памяти в стеке для создания объекта и, возможно, какое то количество в куче - это зависит от класса.

Память в стеке выделяется очень быстро (сместили указатель стека и говото, главное, что бы хватило). Освобождается также. Но в обоих случаях могут быть накладные расходы на вызов конструкторов/деструкторов.

> Может быть, действительно, существует некий минимальный стековый кадр, для которого механизм прост (push ebp  mov ebp, esp  sub esp, N  ...  mov esp, ebp  pop ebp  ret  ...  add esp, N), а при превышении этого размера уже происходит неявное выделение памяти в куче?

Вот такого не видел ни у одного с++ компилятора, хотя теоретически возможно.

Comment: Большое спасибо за внимание и разъяснение!